# How to disable browse option of data source in sitecore item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am facing one issue in sitecore .I want to disable browse option of data source for few items only . For this i have to write pipeline or we can achieve this with some other way . 
Please provide your valuable suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. Suggested answer:

It *looks* like you would override the code for 
/sitecore/shell/applications/content manager/field editor.aspx.

In that code, you would need to disable the data source input and potentially its buttons if you can identify your sublayout. - John West